# Android - How to disable STATE_HALF_EXPANDED state of a bottom sheet

Tags: android, material-components-android

I have a bottom sheet that should go between 2 states, `STATE_COLLAPSED` and `STATE_EXPANDED`
when it's collapsed the hight should be `200dp` and when expanded it will be full screen.

So I'm setting the `BottomSheetBehavior` with

```
isFitToContents = false
peekHeight = 200dp
```

and I'm forced to set a value in `halfExpandedRatio` otherwise when at `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` the bottom sheet will take half of the screen.

I'm working w/ `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-rc01`

Is there a way to disable the `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` state?

Or I should actually set `skipCollapsed=true`, figure out in terms of ratio what 200dp means and work with `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` and `STATE_EXPANDED` instead of `STATE_COLLAPSED` and `STATE_EXPANDED`

Comment: please provide more details such as, how the bottom sheet look like.

Comment: @UD..I don't think that the bottom sheet content is relevant in this case. This is a more general question, is it possible to disable one of the bottom sheet states

Comment: For my use case, it's seems that setting `halfExpandedRatio=0.25f` and `peekHeight = 200dp` and then treating `STATE_COLLAPSED` and `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` as if they are the same state solves the issue.
Keeping the question open in case there are other ideas.

Comment: you can follow this link , it will help https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Comment: Be sure to accept one of these answers, if one meets the objectives set out in your question!

Comment: @CommonsWare - I accepted an answer, thanks for your help

Comment: The problem lies in the isFitToContents flag, you must set it to true to skip the STATE_HALF_EXPANDED state.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:** As mentioned in [another answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62179268/6287910), Material version 1.1.0 and, I presume, subsequent versions of the library have a property `skipCollapsed` that will work as the OP requested. If you are using any of these libraries, that would be the preferred solution.

---

---

The value of the half expanded ratio must be set to some value between 0 and 1 *exclusive*, so set this value to some very low number that is certain to be less than your peek height, say "0.0001f". With this value you should not even see the `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` state. The states will fluctuate between `STATE_EXPANDED` and `STATE_COLLAPSED`.

---

**Alternate solution**

The solution above works and effectively disables the `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` state, but it is hackish  (IMO) and may break in the future. For instance, what if a reasonable value for the half expanded ratio which is somewhere between the peek height and the full height is enforced? That would be trouble.

The requirements as stated by the OP is that the bottom sheet should transition between the peek height and the full height. There is no problem with the peek height, but the OP specifies `isFitToContents = false` to get to the full height. (I assume that his bottom sheet may be shorter then the available space.)

Unfortunately, when `isFitToContents == false` an additional "half-height" behavior is introduced that the OP wants to avoid and therefore the question.

In addition to the "half-height" behavior another behavior is introduced which is the "expanded offset." The expanded offset specifies how far down from full-screen the bottom sheet will stop. A value of `100f`, for instance, will leave a `100px` border at the top of the bottom sheet when fully expanded. The default for the expanded offset is zero.

I am not aware of any behaviors that `isFitToContents == false` introduces other than those mentioned above.

So, given these requirements, can we fashion a bottom sheet that moves between the peek height and the full height while specifying `isFitToContents == true` thus avoiding the "half height" problem? There is no requirement for a non-zero expanded offset, so we don't have to worry about that.

Here is a short demo app demonstrating that we can meet these requirements with the right bottom sheet structure:

[image]

**MainActivity5.kt**

```
class MainActivity5 : BaseActivity() {  
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5)  
  
        val bottomSheet = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.bottom_sheet)  
        val sheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)  
        sheetBehavior.isFitToContents = true // the default  
  sheetBehavior.peekHeight = 200  
  
  // Log the states the bottom sheet passes through.  
  sheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {  
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {  
                Log.d("MainActivity", "<<<< $newState = ${translateSheetState(newState)}")  
            }  
  
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}  
        })  
    }  
}
```

**BaseActivity.kt**

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {  
  
    protected fun translateSheetState(state: Int): String {  
        return when (state) {  
            BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> "STATE_COLLAPSED"  
  BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> "STATE_DRAGGING"  
  BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> "STATE_EXPANDED"  
  BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED -> "STATE_HALF_EXPANDED"  
  BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> "STATE_HIDDEN"  
  BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> "STATE_SETTLING"  
  else -> "Unknown state: $state"  
  }  
    }  
}
```

**activity_main5.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/short_text"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If we have a long bottom sheet then the following structure works to scroll it:

**activity_main6.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/long_text"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: regarding your initial response - I saw that even if I set half expanded ratio, a very slim hint of the bottom sheet is still visible.
And anyway, this isn't the behavior that I'm looking for. as you mentioned in "Alternate solution" - "the bottom sheet should transition between the peek height and the full height"

Comment: your "Alternate solution" seems to be working and it's the solution I needed, my initial testing showed that i need to use `isFitToContents = false`, but testing now w/ `isFitToContents = true` works ok

Comment: @NoaDrach If the bottom sheet is hideable then there would be at least 1px showing at the bottom due to how the bottom sheet offset is calculated. I wasn't thinking that the sheet would be hidden but, with 1px showing, the sheet could just be forced to be hidden `sheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN` when the half expanded state is reached, but that is getting a little complicated. The alternate solution is better.

Answer (score 34):

I am using material library version 1.1.0 and the `BottomSheetBehavior` class has this property `skipCollapsed`, if you set it to `true` the bottom sheet will skip the `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`.

Here is my code:

```
class FilterBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View>

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog

        val view = View.inflate(requireContext(), R.layout.filter_bottom_sheet, null)

        val params = view.root.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams?
        params?.height = getScreenHeight()
        view.root.layoutParams = params

        dialog.setContentView(view)

        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as View)
        behavior.skipCollapsed = true

        return dialog
    }

    private fun getScreenHeight(): Int = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
}
```

Comment: The only answer that has any sense to it, is not a weird trick, and the best part, it works.

Comment: The `behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED` in `onStart` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, to disable the `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` you can use a similar solution by accessing the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`'s `BottomSheetBehavior` and setting `skipCollapsed = true`.

To achieve that, you can override `onViewCreated` method of your implementation of `BottomSheetDialogFragment and access the behavior object of the dialog.

Example (code goes inside your `BottomSheetDialogFragment` implementation):

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dialog?.let {
            val sheet = it as BottomSheetDialog
            sheet.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            sheet.behavior.skipCollapsed = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution does not allow the bottom sheet go to the collapsed state after we switch to the expanded state.

Answer (score 2):

try setting a `addBottomSheetCallback` on your `BottomSheetBehavior`, and when you detect a `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` state, call `setState(STATE_HIDDEN)` so whenever the bottom sheet tries to reach the halfway state, it'll just close.

Comment: nice idea, in my case I would set the state to `STATE_COLLAPSED` and not `STATE_HIDDEN`. But I tried to implement it and the transition from `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` to `STATE_COLLAPSED` feels clunky. The transition between states is animated, so you see the bottom sheet stopping at `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` and then it moves to `STATE_COLLAPSED`

Comment: Could you combine this with a halfExpandedRatio of 0?

Comment: @Ridcully - 2 issues here - 

1. halfExpandedRatio must be above 0 

2. setting it to a very low value will cause it to me minimized almost completely (half expanded state), before being snapped to the collapsed state.

I thought of combining this suggestion w/ my working solution of `halfExpandedState=0.25f`, b/c then the transition between states won't be this obvious. But, I'm not sure that will be a big change compared to what I already have

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `BottomSheetBehavior`[`.setHalfExpandedRatio(0f)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.html?hl=en#sethalfexpandedratio). There is not much else which would affect `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`, unless explicitly setting the state with [.setState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.html?hl=en#setstate). It should also be possible to create a custom `Behavior`, which extends `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>` and does not have `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`. eg. [Intercepting everything with CoordinatorLayout Behaviors](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26).

Comment: That won't work - `halfExpandedRatio` needs to be between 0 and 1 exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

if you want to try above like in image , you can follow below code, may it will help you!!!

```
public class CollectionsBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.collections_layout, null);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.root);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getScreenHeight();
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        dialog.setContentView(view);
        mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
        return dialog;

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }

    public static int getScreenHeight() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }
}



xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/filter_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cancel"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cancel"
                android:drawablePadding="30dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Filters"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Reset ALL"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#d8dbdb" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="GUEST RATINGS"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_money"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_money"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="PRICE RANGE"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_loan"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_star"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="PAY AT HOTEL"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_folder"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_folder"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="COLLECTIONS"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_black_24dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_black_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="FACILITIES"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_apartment"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_apartment"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="CATEGORIES"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sort_background"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_hotel_building"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_hotel_building"
            android:drawablePadding="15dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="ACCOMMODATION TYPE"
            android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried different ways, but no technique worked perfect. I tried intercepting events in `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback {}` and called `dismiss()` based on custom logic but it caused a jerk.

So, at last, In my `BottomSheetDialogFragment` I added **`bottomSheetBehavior.isDraggable = false`** and this caused Dragging of bottom sheet by touch And, I handled the dismissal of dialog on my own. on empty area dialog anyways get dismissed.

Note that, The bottom sheet still expands with animation. That' really great!

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

```
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet =
            bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
                ?: return@setOnShowListener

        //Making background to transparent to avoid white background to given space margin.
        bottomSheet.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.transparent))

        val inflatedView = fragmentProfileDialogBinding.root
        val parent = inflatedView.parent as View

        val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parent)
        bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        bottomSheetBehavior.isDraggable = false
    }

    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In line with other answers, you can disable this in XML by setting `app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"` on the bottom sheet. For example, in my use case:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"
                    app:behavior_hideable="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
                    android:background="@color/colorTransparent">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case where the layout had to be one-third of the height. I tried the following and it worked great.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_sheet_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I had to change these dynamically so I set the following on bottom sheet but you can do this in xml just as well:

```
bottomSheet.setPeekHeight(200);// 200px
bottomSheet.setHideable(false);
```

For dismissing, I added animation to my fragment using the following function:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
                    R.anim.fade_in,
                    R.anim.fade_out,
                    R.anim.fade_in,
                    R.anim.fade_out)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As of more recent versions of MDC, you could alternatively avoid using the aforementioned workarounds by creating a custom `BottomSheetBehavior` that overrides the following methods:

```kotlin
class SkipHalfExpandedBottomSheetBehavior<V: View>(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?) :
    BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attributeSet) {
    override fun shouldSkipHalfExpandedStateWhenDragging() = true
    override fun shouldExpandOnUpwardDrag(
        dragDurationMillis: Long,
        yPositionPercentage: Float
    ) = true
}
```

This seems to work everywhere except for nested scrolling. For that, you would need to patch `onStopNestedScroll` in `BottomSheetBehavior` like this:

```java
@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(
    @NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,
    @NonNull V child,
    @NonNull View target,
    int type) {
  if (child.getTop() == getExpandedOffset()) {
    setStateInternal(STATE_EXPANDED);
    return;
  }
  if (isNestedScrollingCheckEnabled()
      && (nestedScrollingChildRef == null
          || target != nestedScrollingChildRef.get()
          || !nestedScrolled)) {
    return;
  }
  @StableState int targetState;
  if (lastNestedScrollDy > 0) {
    if (fitToContents) {
      targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
    } else {
      int currentTop = child.getTop();
      if (currentTop < halfExpandedOffset) {
        targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
      } else {
        if (shouldSkipHalfExpandedStateWhenDragging()) {
          targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        } else {
          targetState = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED;
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (hideable && shouldHide(child, getYVelocity())) {
    targetState = STATE_HIDDEN;
  } else if (lastNestedScrollDy == 0) {
    int currentTop = child.getTop();
    if (fitToContents) {
      if (Math.abs(currentTop - fitToContentsOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
        targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
      } else {
        targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
      }
    } else {
      if (currentTop < halfExpandedOffset) {
        if (currentTop < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
          targetState = STATE_EXPANDED;
        } else {
          if (shouldSkipHalfExpandedStateWhenDragging()) {
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
          } else {
            targetState = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (shouldSkipHalfExpandedStateWhenDragging()) {
          targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        } else {
          if (Math.abs(currentTop - halfExpandedOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
            targetState = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED;
          } else {
            targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (fitToContents) {
      targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
    } else {
      // Settle to nearest height.
      int currentTop = child.getTop();
      if (shouldSkipHalfExpandedStateWhenDragging()) {
        targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
      } else {
        if (Math.abs(currentTop - halfExpandedOffset) < Math.abs(currentTop - collapsedOffset)) {
          targetState = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED;
        } else {
          targetState = STATE_COLLAPSED;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  startSettling(child, targetState, false);
  nestedScrolled = false;
}
```